# AJAX, response headers are not sent by PHP script!

Tags: php, ajax, response

I'm banging my head for some hours now. I have a select option that it updates a database using AJAX (at least it's trying to!). What happens is while running the PHP script directly with params required the database gets updated but not when running indirectly through AJAX, instead I get 3 times the `alert("There was a problem in the returned data:\n");` and then it gets updated. JavaScript is on `<head>` and not in an external file. Here it goes:

JavaScript:

```
function updateHub(){  
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari  
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
    }else{
        // code for IE6, IE5  
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
    }  
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){  
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){  
           document.getElementById("hubinfo").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;  
       }else{  
           alert("There was a problem in the returned data:\n");  
       }  
    }  
    var prefHub = document.getElementById("prefHub");  
    var hubID = prefHub.options[prefHub.selectedIndex].value;  
    xmlhttp.open("GET","updateHub.php?hubID="+hubID,true);  
    xmlhttp.send();  
}
```

updateHub.php:

```
session_start();
include '../../../common/config.php';
$hubID = '';
if(isset($_POST['hubID'])){
    $hubID = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['hubID'])));
}elseif(isset($_GET['hubID'])){
    $hubID = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_GET['hubID'])));
}
mysql_query("UPDATE prefs set hubID='$hubID' where userID = '".$_SESSION['userID']."'") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_affected_rows()){
    echo "Updated";
}else{
    echo 'Error';
}
return $hubID;
```

and the HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="updateHub();">
    <select name="prefHub" id="prefHub">
        <option value="43">opt1</option>
        <option value="64">opt2</option>
        <option value="30">opt2</option>
     </select>
     <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Hub"/>
</form>
<div id="hubinfo"></div>
```

Comment: Try using a tool like Firebug to see what XHR request is actually being sent (and what response is being returned).

Comment: @Amber i am, no response headers are sent.

Comment: @amber, Exactly. If you aren't using firebug or fiddler, you are most certainly going to have a headache.

Comment: @Byron Whitlock i am using firebug, that's how i see that no response headers are sent

Comment: What url exactly is being sent when using ajax (by looking at firebug)? perhaps the js code messes up there and is requesting something like "updateHub.php?hubID=opt1" .

Comment: Also, what status code is returned?

Comment: @Thr4wn url is as it should be updateHub.php?hubID=64 for example and 200 is returned. I answered my own question solving this problem but i dont really understand why it's running now. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> instead I get 3 times the alert("There
>   was a problem in the returned
>   data:\n");

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("hubinfo").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
else{
alert("There was a problem in the returned data:\n");
}
```

This means that you will always see the alert. Since for any other xmlhttp.readyState values the else {} block will be executed.

---

The XMLHttpRequest object can be in several states. The readyState attribute must return the current state, which must be one of the following values:

UNSENT (numeric value 0)

```
The object has been constructed.
```

OPENED (numeric value 1)

```
The open() method has been successfully invoked. During this state request headers can be set using setRequestHeader() and the request can be made using the send() method.
```

HEADERS_RECEIVED (numeric value 2)

```
All redirects (if any) have been followed and all HTTP headers of the final response have been received. Several response members of the object are now available.
```

LOADING (numeric value 3)

```
The response entity body is being received.
```

DONE (numeric value 4)

Comment: didn't see your post before i post my answer. now i got it. thank you

Comment: no problem. I think this is why you see the alert so many times. One alert for each state of the XMLHttpRequest object (OPENED,HEADERS_RECEIVED,LOADING)

Answer (score 0):

I moved

```
var prefHub = document.getElementById("prefHub");
var hubID = prefHub.options[prefHub.selectedIndex].value;
```

right after

```
function updateHub()
{
```

and removed

```
else{
         alert("There was a problem in the returned data:\n");
    }
```

and it's now working properly but I don't understand why.Is anyone able to explain it?

andreas explained why.

Comment: if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
  if (xmlhttp.status==200) {
    //handle response
  } else {
    //handle error
  }
}